# Building Shopping Cart Compatible with Non-JavaScript enabled Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopping-cart

I am building an on-line shop, I have decided to build my own shopping cart, I know there a lot of out of the box solutions, but its only a small shop and i prefer a best spoke solution.

I want to mate the shop compatible with non-JavaScript Script Browsers, so i have been considering the best way to do it.

I am considering doing something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('form').each(function() {
               $(this).removeAttr('action')
      });

});
 </script>

<div>Product Description</div>

<form action="/addproduct.php" method="post">

<select name="size">
<option>Small</option>
<option>Medium</option>
<option>Large</option>
<option>X Large</option>
</select>

<input onclick="AddProduct();" value="Add Product" type="submit">
</form>
```

Any comment or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you are submitting form with AJAX...no need to remove the `action`. If not submitting with AJAX... where will form submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to do something like this:

```
$('form').each(function() {
    $(this).submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //So that the form is not submitted.
        //Add the product to the cart.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or not hardcode onclick="AddProduct();" and add some magics actions to form by id in JS.